# Sync React-Router Routes across clients

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a React App which is supposed to be used from one device only. If say another client connects to my App I want him to be on the exact same route like any other client using that App. I do not need to keep the whole state of the App and share it with the others. But at least the Routes should match. The rest of the state will be updated by regular Socket.IO events anyways.

My React-Router looks like this atm:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Menu from '../../pages/Menu/Menu';
import Timelapse from '../../pages/Timelapse/Timelapse';
import Panorama from '../../pages/Panorama/Panorama';
import Movie from '../../pages/Movie/Movie';
import Running from '../../pages/Running/Running';

function Main() {

  return (
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Menu} />
        <Route path="/timelapse" component={Timelapse} />
        <Route path="/panorama" component={Panorama} />
        <Route path="/movie" component={Movie} />
        <Route path={"/runningTimelapse"} render={(props) => <Running {...props} type={'timelapse'} />} />
        <Route path={"/runningPanorama"} render={(props) => <Running {...props} type={'panorama'} />} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  );
}


export default Main;
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './components/Main/Main';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';
import './App.css';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import SocketContext from './services/SocketProvider'
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack';


const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
    secondary: green,
  },
});

function App() {
  const socket = io("http://172.20.10.2:8000");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
        <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={3} dense={true} anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center'}}>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Main />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      </SnackbarProvider>
      </SocketContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you not use socket.io to send over what the current route is? From there you can just redirect everytime the client recieves a change route request

Comment: @Sasha I think you're right, I need somehow to save that state server-side. How would I load my App based on a `socket.on('receiveRoute', function(){...})` event? Do I put this directly into my `App.js` before my actual `return` statement? I added my `App.js` to the question.

Comment: You would store the current route on the server side, when any client connects to the server they can receive the current route. When any client goes to a new route, you can send that route to the server which sends the route to other clients, which should initiate a redirect. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: `<Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/"
            }}
          />` this helps a lot! Thanks for your help :)